# Did the U.S. Space Shuttles have a way for crew to bail out?

Tags: space-shuttle, safety

[This recent question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/51232/2900) regarding the Space Shuttle Columbia disaster mentions the possibility that the crew could have bailed out if the orbiter could have successfully descended to 25,000 feet before it broke up.

Was this indeed something that was possible? I do seem to recall hearing that some of the seats were ejection seats early on in the Space Shuttle program, but that not all of them were and that they were subsequently removed from the design. Was there some other way for the crew to (survivably) bail out in place at the time of the Columbia disaster? Did the crew even have personal parachutes for such a situation and a survivable method of egress in flight?

Comment: See here for more on the shuttle ejection seats: https://space.stackexchange.com/q/19398/6944

Comment: See here for more on the Space Shuttle Orbiter's bailout mode: https://space.stackexchange.com/a/12782/12422

Answer (score 25, accepted):

They did, but its use case was pretty narrow.

The shuttle hatch was modified to be able to be explosively jettisoned, and a telescoping escape pole (pictured below) could be deployed that would help bailing crew members clear the wing on the way out.  The vehicle, however, had to be in a stable glide and below 25,000 feet, which pretty severely limits the number of applicable situations.  (Reference: [Shuttle News Reference](https://web.archive.org/web/20210307054042/https://science.ksc.nasa.gov/shuttle/technology/sts-newsref/sts_egress.html))

This system was installed after the loss of Challenger; it might not have helped in that case, but would have made engine failures on ascent over the mid-Atlantic more survivable.

[image: Shuttle escape pole test]

Comment: The system was only _tested_ in stable flight at ≤25 kft, but the parachutes would have been useful even if the orbiter lost control and/or broke up in flight, _iff_ one or more crewmembers were able to get out the door (something which would probably be more difficult with the crew cabin tumbling uncontrollably) and avoid colliding with anything at high relative speeds.  Had the _Challenger_ crew been equipped with parachutes and full-body pressure suits, some of them might well have survived (the forces of the breakup itself were well within human tolerance, and the crew cabin did remain...

Comment: ...intact until water impact).

Comment: @Vikki-formerlySean I changed the phrasing of my edit, but I'm skeptical that they could have egressed the tumbling cabin.

Comment: @RussellBorogove: Manually bailing out of an out-of-control vehicle often _can_ be done (as huge numbers of WWII bomber crewmen can, or, at least, previously could, testify, as well as quite a few pilots of skydiving flights where something went very wrong), although it does depend quite strongly on the details of just how the crew cabin is tumbling/falling (and, for some tumble modes, you are quite right - escape would likely have been difficult to impossible).

Comment: @Vikki-formerlySean the "Loss of Control / Breakup" cue card https://space.stackexchange.com/a/42090/6944

Comment: @Tristan, nice photo! A shout-out to the courageous, mostly unheralded test-jumpers out at Edwards AFB. This testing was quite dangerous...

Comment: @Digger It sure highlights the severity of the situation.  I heard stories about some of the subscale wind tunnel testing when they were developing the idea.  Closest I ever got to that hardware was banging my head on the CCT-2 mockup in Building 9 during a tour.